# How to find destination and starting place in a document?

Tags: nlp

Given a document, how do I find the starting place and destination in the document? For example, in the sentence " On 12/08/2017: 11.00 welcome guide at 130 Quan Thanh to Noi Bai for international trip SQ176 SIN-HAN landed at 11.40am to Gondola 31 Hang Hanh Hotel.", the starting place is 130 Quan Thanh and the destination is Noi Bai. Are there any advances in NLP help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think NER would be useful for your task. 
[image]

The issue is, many of the city names you have mentioned (Vietnamese names?) are not common English destinations and they wouldn't be captured easily. So you can update an NER system's gazetteers with your city/destination names.

Btw this might be useful for you: http://deagol.cs.illinois.edu:8080